# Craft CMS max image resolution?

Tags: assets, upload

Is there a max image file resolution set up in Craft CMS that can be uploaded?

I'm trying to upload a series of .jpg images in a Matrix to create a gallery, and I've noticed I'm not able to upload any file that is over somewhere around 4000px in width.

At first I believed it was something to do with the PHP file upload limit, but I'm able to upload .jpg files that were over 5mb with a 2880px width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Craft does have the [maxUploadFileSize](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#maxUploadFileSize) config setting (defaults to 16MB).  If what you're trying to upload is under that size, you're probably running into environmental limitations.  I'd check your php.ini file's post_max_size, memory_limit and max_execution_time settings as a starting point.

Comment: I recently switched the site from my MAMP, over to the live server in a dev folder for loading assets. I believe it may be something to do with file permissions, as I've had to make quite a few changes. This is my first Craft build so I'm sure I'm forgetting something easy.

PHP Version 5.3.29
post_max_size: 100M
memory_limit: 96M
max_execution_time: 90